# How Lucene Cache The Data?

Tags: java, lucene

How Lucene cache the data ?

Does it use memory cache ?

or

It uses static file for caching data ?

Comment: Caching of search result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lucene allows for some low-level caching of certain data structures (like the FieldCache) but this is more to allow for custom functionality.

If you're looking to cache search results, you might want to look into Solr.  It comes with all kinds of caches out of the box.  See http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCaching .  But I have found that OS buffer caching (which happens automatically) makes Lucene searches fast enough.

Without providing any more detail about your situation, it's difficult to recommend a good caching strategy for you.